# Email not formatted as Html

Tags: wordpress, html-email

I’ve set up the POST SMTP plugin, and I’m getting the emails. However its not arriving as HTML format, even though Post SMTP log shows it as a HTML. The content of the email is correct, only problem it shows as plain text. Any idea how can i fix this?

Code that sends the email is:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

try { wp_mail($to, $subject, $this->getResult()); } 
catch (Exception $e) { $result = false; }  

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

function set_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

Here is the email I get:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="hu">

<head>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="DYB Group - http://dyb.hu/" />
        <meta name="Description" content='' />

        <title>i-Cell díjbekérő</title>

</head> 

<body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="98%" style="background:#f4f4f4; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; color:#404040; text-align:center; table-layout:fixed;">

                                <tr style="line-height:0px;">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="1000" height="80" >Dokumentum letöltése PDF formátumban:<a href="https://dybtest.hu/utdijfizetes/pdfgen?type=request&hash=53779fbd5102127635542ccd50e465c8" target="_blank">kattintson ide</a></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="1000" style="background:#fff; line-height:24px;">
                                <table width="1000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-bottom:2px solid #ccc; text-align:left; table-layout:fixed;">

                                        <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td width="800" style="font-family: Arial; vertical-align:middle;">




                                                        <h1 style='text-align: left; text-transform:uppercase; color:#666; font-size:24px; font-family: Verdana; vertical-align:middle;'>
                                                                <img src="http://icell.hu/mail/fejlec.jpg" alt="i-Cell" height="60px">
                                                                Díjbekérő
                                                        </h1>


                                                        <table style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
                                                                <tr>


                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; white-space: nowrap; padding:20px;" valign="top" width='50%'>
                                                                                <h2 style='text-transform:uppercase; color:#f36f21; font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; font-family: Verdana;'>Szállító</h2>
                                                                                <p>
                                                                                        <strong style="font-size: 18px;">i-Cell Kft</strong><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">1143 Budapest</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Hungária köz 5.</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Adószám: 11756420-2-42</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Cégj. szám: 01-09-674965</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Bank neve: MKB Bank Zrt.</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">SWIFT: MKKBHUHB</span>
                                                                                </p>
                                                                        </td>


                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:20px" valign="top">
                                                                                <h2 style='text-transform:uppercase; color:#f36f21; font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; font-family: Verdana;'>Vevő</h2>
                                                                                <p>
                                                                                        <strong style="font-size: 18px;">Tóth András</strong><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Ország: Magyarország</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Székhely: 1112, Budapest, Löveg utca 3/f, 2/2</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Szállítási cím: Magyarország: 1112, Budapest, Löveg utca 3/f, 2/2</span><br />

                                                                                                                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">Adószám: 0123456789</span><br />


                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">E-mail: totand92@gmail.com</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Mobilszám: 203169271</span><br />
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">Fizetési mód: Banki átutalás</span><br />

                                                                                                                                                                        </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                        </table>

                                                        <table style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: center; padding-top:20px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase; color:#f36f21; margin-top:20px;  font-family: Verdana;">Díjbekérő sorszáma</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: center; padding-top:20px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase; color:#f36f21; margin-top:20px;  font-family: Verdana;">Díjbekérő kelte</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: center; padding-top:20px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase; color:#f36f21; margin-top:20px;  font-family: Verdana;">Fizetési határidő</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: small;">D18/2775</span></td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: small;">2018-08-14</span></td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: small;">2018-08-21</span></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                        </table>


                                                        <div>
                                                        <table style="width: 100%; text-align:left; table-layout:fixed;" cellpadding="4">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td style="background:#f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Termék neve</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="background:#f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Mennyiség (db)</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="background:#f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Egységár (HUF)</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="background:#f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Nettó összesen (HUF)</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="background:#f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>ÁFA kulcs (%)</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="background:#f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>ÁFA (HUF)</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="background:#f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Bruttó összesen (HUF)</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>


                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>OBU S550</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">1</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">29900</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">29900</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">27</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">8073</span>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: right; padding-right: 20px;">
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">37973</span>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                                                        </tr>










                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Kiszállítási költség</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">1</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">0</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">0</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: small;">27</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; padding: 2px;">
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">0</span>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: right; padding-right: 20px;">
                                                                                        <span style="font-size: small;">0</span>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                                                        </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0; table-layout:fixed;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td style="background-color: #f36f21; width: 60%; padding-left: 20px; height:40px;">

                                                                                <span style="font-size: 16px; color:#fff">
                                                                                                                                                                                        <strong>Számlaszám: (HU11) 10300002-10590929-49020015</strong>
                                                                                                                                                                        </span>

                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="background-color: #f36f21; width: 40%; padding-left: 20px; height:40px;">
                                                                                <span style="font-size: 16px; color:#fff"><strong>Fizetendő: 37973 HUF</strong></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        </div>


                                                        <table>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="font-size: small; padding-bottom: 1em; text-decoration: underline;">
                                                                                <strong>
                                                                                        Amennyiben az Ön cége EU tagországbeli, akkor kérjük, fokozottan ügyeljen az EU adószám pontos megadására! Hibásan megadott EU adószám esetén sajnos nincs módunkban ÁFA mentes számlát küldeni, így ebben az esetben a számlán fel fogjuk számítani a magyar törvények szerinti 27 % ÁFA-t!
                                                                                </strong>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="font-size: small; padding-bottom: 1em; text-decoration: underline;">
                                                                                <strong>A díjbekérő fizetési kötelezettséget nem tartalmaz!</strong>
                                                                                Jelen díjbekérő ÁFA visszaigénylésre nem jogosít.
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="font-size: small; padding-bottom: 1em;">
                                                                                Kérjük, hogy a megrendelt termékek ellenértékeként utalja át a jelen Díjbekérőn szereplő összeget az i-Cell Kft. számlaszámára.
                                                                                <strong style="color:#f36f21">Kérjük fizetéskor – a banki megjegyzés rovatban - mindig hivatkozzon a díjbekérő (vagy az OBU) sorszámára!</strong>
                                                                                A pénzügyi teljesítést követően a számlát a megrendelt termékekkel együtt küldjük ki.
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="font-size: small; padding-bottom: 1em;">
                                                                                A pontatlan adatmegadás (szállítási cím, értesítési mobil szám) miatt a termékek ismételt kézbesítéséből származó esetleges pluszköltség a Vevőt terheli.
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="font-size: small; padding-bottom: 1em;">
                                                                                Magyarországon belüli termék kiszállítás esetén a szállítás díját 10.000 Ft feletti megrendelés esetén az i-Cell Kft. fizeti, a Vevő részére díjmentes.
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="font-size: small; padding-bottom: 1em;">
                                                                                Külföldre történő szállítás esetén a kiszállítási díjat a Vevő fizeti. A kiszállítási díj a termékekkel együtt kerül kiszámlázásra.
                                                                        </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                        </table>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td width="800" height="80">
                                                        </td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="1000" style="background-color:#e8e8e8; text-align:center;">
                                <table width="1000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; text-align:center; table-layout:fixed;">
                                        <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td width="800" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td width="800" height="20" valign="top" style="line-height:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
                                                        <h2 style='font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; color:#f36f21;'>i-Cell Kft.
                                                </td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td width="800" height="28" valign="bottom" style="line-height:22px;">
                                                        <b>Cím:</b> 1143 Budapest Hungária köz 5. <b style='margin-left:20px'>E-mail: </b>info@icell.hu <b style='margin-left:20px'>Tel.:</b> +36 (1) 467 1750
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td width="800" height="100">
                                                        <img src="http://icell.hu/mail/lablec.png" alt="i-Cell" width="800px">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="1000" height="65" valign="bottom" style="text-align:center; font-size:11px; line-height:15px; color:#404040;">
                                Ez az e-mail az i-Cell Kft. rendszeréből lett kiküldve.<br>
                                A rendszerben lévő adatokat bizalmasan kezeljük, harmadik fél számára nem adjuk ki.
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td height="55">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove following lines as remove filter also gets registered on the go.

```
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
```

Comment: If I remove the function, how add_filter gonna work?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean to say that remove_filter line should be removed, not function.

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to solve this. Thing what finally worked is:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function () { return 'text/html'; } );
try { wp_mail($to, $subject, $this->getResult()); }
catch (Exception $e) { $result = false; }
```